# mysql update int column from 2 other int columns where result is a negative

Tags: mysql

I have 3 columns a,b,c.  A = 3 B =4, I'm trying to perform an update statement that can handle negative.  For example in this case i should get -1, but instead I get the error Out of range value for column 'C' at row 1.  All columns are ints.

Any suggestions would be awesome!

```
update tbl
set c = a - b
where uniqueID = 49
```

Comment: Could it be that column `C` is marked as `UNSIGNED`?

Comment: nope it's not, it turns the result into 2147483647

Comment: AHHH columb A was set to unsigned, i changed it and it resolved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check column `C` definition, it might be set as `UNSIGNED`.

**EDIT**

Check definition of all columns involved in the calculation.  If *any* of them is marked as `UNSIGNED`, then all calculations will be done usign `UNSGINED` arithmetic with can result in the `Out of range value` error.